# Can you shoot through an enemy Reinhardt's shield, on his side?

Tags: overwatch

To exemplify the question I'll create a scenario.

The enemy team has a Reinhardt and Mei that are being particularly troublesome, we have a tracer that flanks around the rear of Reinhardt and sees the enemy Mei, the tracer decides to target the Mei as she has the ability to slow down the tracer.

In this scenario, could the friendly tracer shoot through the enemy Reinhardt's shield (from his side of the shield) to then hit Mei?

[image: Crude diagram of Tracer shooting at Mei through Reinhardt's shield]

Comment: Should've been hand-drawn circles!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev http://imgur.com/NVXjFFi

Comment: That's what I'm talking about :)

Comment: @Sergio wtfffffffff

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. Shields absorb enemy projectiles from both sides. Likewise, allies can fire through it from both sides. That is, the team the shield belongs to determines whether projectiles pass through it.

My only source is primary: approximately 150 hours of play, much of it as Reinhardt.

Comment: This is also true for Winston's bubble, if you are inside an opposing team's bubble, you cannot shoot out, even though it is his original side.

Comment: @JamesCW indeed jumping on a turret and using the shield is a good way to push into an area with a hard to get to turret

Comment: Thanks @JamesCW, didn't know that -- good to know I haven't been doing something dumb with Winston when I back out of the bubble as enemies are entering it.

Comment: @TomOlson yeah, that is a key skill when you are 1v1 as Winston, managing to keep your shield in between you and your opponent, regardless of who is inside and who is outside. If only it had more hp, I find that it falls really quickly in teamfights.